# What is Persistence Context?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence

I am new to the Java world and JPA. I was studying JPA and came across many new terms like Entity, persistence. While reading, I could not understand the exact definition for **Persistence Context**.

Can anyone explain it in simple laymen terms? What is it to do with the data used in the `@Entity`?

For example, I find this definition too complicated to understand:

> A persistence context is a set of entities such that for any persistent identity there is a unique entity instance.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A persistence context handles a set of entities which hold data to be persisted in some persistence store (e.g. a database). In particular, the context is aware of the different states an entity can have (e.g. managed, detached) in relation to both the context and the underlying persistence store.

Although Hibernate-related (a JPA provider), I think these links are useful:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch03.html

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/architecture.html

In Java EE, a persistence context is normally accessed via an EntityManager.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

The various states an entity can have and the transitions between these are described below:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/objectstate.html

https://vladmihalcea.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/jpaentitystates.png

Comment: hmmm, it makes sense now. Do you have a similar "Simple" definition which tells the difference between container-managed & application-managed Entity Managers?

Comment: container vs application just basically tells where Entity Manager is created - outside in a container, or inside, in application.

Answer (score 89):

1. Entities are managed by **javax.persistence.EntityManager** instance **using persistence context.**
2. Each **EntityManager** instance is associated with **a** ***persistence context***.
3. Within the **persistence context**, the entity instances and their **lifecycle are managed.**
4. **Persistence context** defines a **scope** under which **particular** entity instances are created, persisted, and removed.
5. A **persistence context** is like a ***cache*** which contains a set of **persistent entities** , So once the **transaction is finished**, all persistent objects are detached from the **EntityManager's persistence context** and are no longer managed.

Comment: I found that EclipseLink does not detach entities after a transaction is finished...

Comment: The container managed persistence context's cache will only remain for the duration of the transaction. Entities read in a transaction will become detached after the completion of the transaction and will require to be merged to be edited in subsequent transactions. [EclipseLink](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/cache001.htm). @RayHulha

Comment: @pritamkumar, you explained well the concept of a persistence context. I'd just add that there's also the javax.persistence.PersistenceContext annotation, which is used to inject an EntityManager object and establish the scope of the injected object (e.g., a transaction).

Comment: so why isnt this an implementation detail and why do I have to manually specify my EntityManager to use a PersistenceContext ?

Answer (score 52):

Taken from [this](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html) page:

Here's a quick cheat sheet of the JPA world:

- A Cache is a copy of data, copy meaning pulled from but living outside the database.
- Flushing a Cache is the act of putting modified data back into the database.
- A PersistenceContext is essentially a Cache. It also tends to have it's own non-shared database connection.
- An EntityManager represents a PersistenceContext (and therefore a Cache)
- An EntityManagerFactory creates an EntityManager (and therefore a PersistenceContext/Cache)

Comment: can one PersisnteceContext have any EntityManager instances?  And can one Entity Manager have any PersistenceContext?  PersisntenceContext is only one for all application?

Answer (score 10):

Both the `org.hibernate.Session` API and `javax.persistence.EntityManager` API represent a context for dealing with persistent data.

This concept is called a **persistence context**. Persistent data has a state in relation to both a persistence context and the underlying database.

Answer (score 10):

A **persistent context** represents the entities which hold data and are qualified to be persisted in some persistent storage like a database. Once we `commit` a transaction under a session which has these entities attached with, *Hibernate flushes the persistent context* and changes(**insert/save, update or delete**) on them are persisted in the persistent storage.

Answer (score 7):

In layman terms we can say that Persistence Context is an environment where entities are managed, i.e it syncs "Entity" with the database.

Answer (score 6):

**Persistence Context** is an **environment** or **cache** where entity instances(which are capable of holding data and thereby having the ability to be persisted in a database) are managed by **Entity Manager**.It syncs the entity with database.All objects having **@Entity** annotation are capable of being persisted.
**@Entity** is nothing but a class which helps us create objects in order to communicate with the database.And the way the objects communicate is using methods.And who supplies those methods is the Entity Manager.

Comment: How is this answer different from the existing answers?

Answer (score 5):

"A set of persist-able  (entity) instances managed by an entity manager instance at a given time" is called persistence context.

JPA @Entity annotation indicates a persist-able entity.

Refer JPA [Definition here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm)

Answer (score 4):

While @pritam kumar gives a good overview the 5th point is not true.

> Persistence Context can be either Transaction Scoped-- the Persistence
>   Context 'lives' for the length of the transaction, or Extended-- the
>   Persistence Context spans multiple transactions.

https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_caching

JPA's EntityManager and Hibernate's Session offer an extended Persistence Context.

Comment: Hi user2771889, You are right I didn't mention the extended scope of persistence context. 5th point was just related to transaction scoped persistence context.

Answer (score 0):

The persistence context is the first-level cache where all the entities are fetched from the database or saved to the database.