# Using different entity managers in different EJBs within the same single transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, eclipselink, entitymanager

```
Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 1L);

if (employee == null) {
    throw new EntityNotFoundException();
}
```

Since `EntityManager#find()` returns `null` in case, the said entity is unavailable, the conditional test as shown above is necessary to avoid the possible `java.lang.NullPointerException` which is otherwise likely. Repeating this trivial conditional test everywhere is pretty much unacceptable and discouraged which makes the business logic which should in turn be as simple as possible, pretty much unreadable.

To prevent this conditional check from being repeated all over the place, I have a generic method in a separate EJB like so,

```
@Stateless
public class EntityManagerUtils implements EntityManagerService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public <T extends Object> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey) {
        T entity = entityManager.find(entityClass, primaryKey);

        if (entity == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Invoking this method from inside another EJB like the following,

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestBeanService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerService entityManagerService;

    @Override
    public void test(Employee employee) {
        Department managedDepartment = entityManagerService.find(Department.class, employee.getDepartment().getDepartmentId());
        System.out.println("contains : " + entityManager.contains(managedDepartment));
    }
}
```

Here, despite the fact that everything happens within the same single transaction, `entityManager.contains(managedDepartment)` returns `true` i.e. the returned `Department` entity is managed by both the `EntityManager`s in both the EJBs.

Although it is expected, how does `entityManager.contains(managedDepartment)` return true?

Is it the same `EntityManager` instance using the same `EntityManagerFactory`?

Comment: Like EJBs, they are proxies too (referring to one associated with current transaction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt the EJB specification guarantees that the `EntityManager` Java instances will be the same, but it guarantees they are backed by the same [Persistence Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930152/what-is-persistence-context) (the same set of managed entities), because you are in the same JTA transaction and because both `EntityManagers` are container managed of the same persistence unit (the default in your case).

If you want to check whether the instances are the same in your environment, check the output of

```
System.out.println("EntityManager : " + entityManager);
```

but I would not rely on that as a guarantee for future versions of your Application Server.

If you want a new Persistence Context, you could either begin a new transaction or create manually an `EntityManager` instance from an injected `EntityManagerFactory`.

For performace considerations, I wouldn't want to use a new Persistence Context in your situation.

**Edit:** Add a quote from [official JavaEE 7 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm#BNBQW) that explains/justify what it was just said

> The persistence context is automatically propagated with the current
>   JTA transaction, and **`EntityManager` references that are mapped to the
>   same persistence unit provide access to the persistence context within
>   that transaction**. By automatically propagating the persistence
>   context, application components don't need to pass references to
>   `EntityManager` instances to each other in order to make changes within
>   a single transaction. The Java EE container manages the lifecycle of
>   container-managed entity managers.

Comment: Hey VG, I have some questions related to this topic. Can I reach you please?