# @PersistentContext: Could someone explain that annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new in Hibernate and JPA and I have problem with this annotation. Could someone explain me in simple words what this annotation actually doing, becouse documentation is hard to understand for me in this case.

EDIT
I understand what Persistent Context is, but in code I have for example something like that:

```
@Repository
public class AbstractRepository<E extends Identifable> implements IRepository<E> {

private Class<E> clazz;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
```

And I have problem with what @PersistenceContext doing. Sorry, Maybe I was not specific.

Comment: Hmm, dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930152/what-is-persistence-context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Persistence Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930152/what-is-persistence-context)

Comment: I hope my answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

A PersistenContext is aware of your DataSource,JPA properties, Entities etc.
As already described here: [What is Persistence Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930152/what-is-persistence-context)
You can use it to do some manual stuff in your repository. Eg. handle transactions.
I used it a few times in older projects with horrible designed databases.
Normally it should not be necessary. 
Spring can nearly handle everything if your database is designed well.

Maybe this helps you:

```
    public void saveMovie() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setId(1L);
    movie.setMovieName("The Godfather");
    movie.setReleaseYear(1972);
    movie.setLanguage("English");

    em.persist(movie);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entitymanager

If you don't need to do something special you can just define a repository interface without any implementation.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories